# Does Mean stack have application server and web server?

Tags: mean-stack

In WAMP server, you have a web server APACHE, so in MEAN does one of the letters serve as web server? 
And what about application server in a MEAN stack?

Answer (score 3):

I think it easiest to explain this from the bottom-up. MEAN is an acronym for MongoDB-Angular-Express-Node. MongoDB is the database system and Angular is a front-end framework. They are not relevant to this discussion.

Node is a Javascript runtime built upon the V8 engine (which is also the Javascript engine used by Chrome). It allows us to write Javascript applications that runs outside the browser. Node applications can be command line applications, but are usually made for the web.

Node itself comes with a [library](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) that allows us to write a web server. However, it's very time consuming and error prone to write it completely from scratch ourselves, so some people made Express, which is a web application framework built for Node.

Express will make it easier for us to write web servers. It will handle all the boilerplate stuff, deals with routing, has a system for middleware and so on.

So the definition of a web server in the MEAN stack is:
Node + Express + your code

As you can see, your code is needed to make it a web server. Node + Express will not act as a server by itself. Express is only a framework that makes it easy for us to make the server and Node is the system that enables us to use Javascript outside the browser (i.e. on the server). A small web server only has to be a few lines of code though.